# How to: change permalink by category?

Tags: permalinks

i'm have 2 category: News & Games

How to change permalink by category as:

if is category `News` permalink as: `domain.com/news-%postname%`

if is category `Game` permalink as: `domain.com/play-%postname%`

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Open to admin dashboard > Settings > Permalinks, select "Custom Structure", enter:

```
/%category%-%postname%/
```

and click "Save Changes". Or, you might consider separating the two with a forward slash:

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

Using the /%category%-%postname%/ custom permalink structure, the `News` category will show as `/news-%postname%`. For the `Game` category, since the name is different than the desired permalink, you can edit the category: leave the Name as "Game", change the Slug to "play" and you'll have `/play-%postname%`.

Comment: Hi Gabriel, if my category Name is: `Games Online` how to change Permalinks to : `play-%postname%` ???

Comment: @DinhTv - Using `/%category-%postname%/` as described above, edit your category named `Games Online` and change just the Slug to "play".